# How do you make apt-get install faster?

Tags: debian, apt, performance, download

I just installed Debian for the first time in a virtual-machine (I have used centos/RHEL/fedora for the last 11 years so I have some Linux experience). I did an apt-get install gcc... the command took about 15 minutes! Because the download speed was on the order of magnitude of 30 KB/s (bytes). I tested my connection and it has a download speed of 7 MB/s (bytes).

**How do you make apt-get install faster?**

---

UPDATE:

I am not experiencing slowdown anymore. I also can't seem to recreate the slowdown that I was earlier. So I can't debug or fix something when the issue goes away and can't be recreated.

Comment: Are you using `httpredir`?

Comment: I don't know what is `httpredir` and I am not sure how to check whether `httpredir` is on or off.

Comment: I google'd `httpredir` and from what I read `httpredir` just replaces the absolute URL in sources.list with a different URL. My `/etc/apt/sources.list` has `deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main` instead of `http://httpredir.debian.org/debian` so I don't think I have `httpredir` enabled.

Comment: Are you planning in using only one server, or will you be using more servers? If in a corporate setting, I can give you a solution.

Comment: Ok. Well, try using `httpredir` and see how it goes.The idea is that it automatically chooses a fast mirror for you.

Answer (score 2):

Well it could have been that the mirror had problems, it happens some times like this [reddit discussion between users who had buggy mirrors](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/39pclt/dear_debian_users_you_can_speed_up_your_aptget/)
and you should report when it happens to mirrors@debian.org and they will get to you right away.

You could change the mirrors in your  /etc/apt/sources.list to mirrors nearer to where you live from this site https://www.debian.org/mirror/list .

for instance :

`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main`.

can be changed to

`deb ftp.br.debian.org/debian stretch main` .

If i live in brazil or maybe brazil is just faster at this moment .

Or you could just change to `httpredir` mirrors which just chooses for you the best mirror
`deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch main` .

And you could read here for more examples https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Comment: I'm confused, he didn't mention `httpredir`, and also `httpredir` is supposed to pick a mirror based on which one is "best". And `httpredir` works well for me.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha that is correct but sometimes the server/mirror nearest to you as determined by httpredir has problems and therfore is slower than a slightly further mirror chosen by you

Comment: @FaheemMitha you could read this https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/39pclt/dear_debian_users_you_can_speed_up_your_aptget/  too as this problem sometimes happens and is a bit weird

Comment: Well, `httpredir` has been working well for me, and I think for other people too. I recommend at least trying that in the first instance.

Comment: @FaheemMitha it has never failed me too  but its not like it will never fail ,everything has its limits and `httpredir` is just an algorithm/embedded logic <<>>i am sure he had `httpredir` because it is the default and it obviously was not working for him and as you could read on the link i supplied before, this is not a first timer

Comment: Well, he doesn't mention `httpredir` in his question. So I don't see how you can conclude it is not working for him. And since when is `httpredir` the default?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha I had it like that on different fresh installations and i guess it was just a pure intuitive guess based on what i see, maybe i was wrong but still he didn't complain , yet .

Comment: Maybe that's the case on recent fresh installations. I haven't done one of those recently. Did you get that on a jessie, testing or unstable installation?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha ordinary jessie and  wheezy , maybe it was just an option i clicked while installing , it became mechanical for me after a while cause i always test with the kernel or drivers and i end up killing the installation and reinstalling

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm not sure if I've ever done a wheezy or jessie installation from scratch.

Comment: @Faheem  Mitha Well, i still could be wrong , i became very stupid lately

Comment: Not a really good advice. I have used USA for ages because local mirrors are often slower, often outdated, and too many times only support an handful of arquitectures. Back a few years in South Africa, the local mirrors did not even were signed (when I was an expat there)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro  I use the south-Africa mirrors and they are very fast  but for instance japan has weirdly behaving mirrors ,sometimes they are slow and other times they are very good, it depends on many variables ,so trial won't hurt i guess.

Comment: Obviously. I also often update as soon the security list announces the updates, and quite before they even appear announced in the Debian site...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I hate updates, they mostly come with alterations to the GUI/ some security issue and the program just gets slower and slower withe every update till a new version is produced and the loop starts all over

Comment: In windows ;) In Linux they do not bring new hidden functionalities, only bug fixes. I also do a proper evaluation wether they are urgent or not.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro you are absolutely right, i rarely encounter that problem in linux but in any commercial O.S. it is very common.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro i guess its because marketing people are above the engineers in the non-free world like win#@$! so they always force them to add irrelevant glamorous stuff....actually i hate marketing people a lot, they always deviate concentration to stupid shiny things with the argument that people are stupid and they like shiny stuff....if you mean by extra functionality >>malicious ,yeah probably too